# AWS powershell credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata

Tags: powershell, aws-cli, aws-powershell, aws-sdk-net

I'm trying to set the `credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata` option in the profile config file so applications/tools running on an EC2 can assume a specific role rather than the Instance Profile role.

I have the following config file at `c:\aws\config`

```
[SomeUser]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAXXX
aws_secret_access_key = zzzz

[profile RoleA]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::1111111:role/RoleA
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata

[profile RoleB]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::1111111:role/RoleB
source_profile = SomeUser
```

To set the profile for the current Powershell session, I run this command

`PS C:\> Set-AWSCredentials -ProfileName RoleA -ProfileLocation c:\aws\config`.

However, it throws the error

`Set-AWSCredentials : Credential profile [RoleA] is not valid.  Please ensure the profile contains a valid combination of properties.`

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html), `credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata` is a valid option but if I remove the `RoleA` profile from the config file it accepts the command, leading me to believe that option is not recognized.

Once that role is removed and I pass `RoleB` as the `ProfileName` with the `Set-AWSCredentials` command, I can run other AWS CLI commands that assume `RoleB` (in this case credentials are taken from the IAM user credentials of `[SomeUser]`). But this is not what I want as I do not want to have IAM credentials stored on the instance.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

P.S.
I have the following versions for AWS PS tooling (`Get-AWSPowerShellVersion`)

```
Amazon Web Services SDK for .NET: Core Runtime Version 3.3.22.5
AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell: Version 3.3.283.0`
```

Comment: Is the PowerShell updated to latest version?

Answer (score 1):

This is a missing feature in the AWS SDK for .NET which the AWS PowerShell tooling is based on. Can you open a GitHub issue in our repository to help track this feature. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net